# group by from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use `group by` from multiple columns?

Here is the `members` table:

```
Id | CateogryId | Value
1  | 1          | 10
2  | 2          | 20
1  | 1          | 10
```

Currently, I'm able to return the `(A,B)` using:

```
( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT members.Category) 
    FROM members 
    JOIN categories on members.CategoryId = category.Id
         ) as "Categories"
```

But I also want the total next to each of the category, for instance `(A:20, B:20)`

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax.  I'm looking to group_concat from multiple columns including summing up for one of the columns.

Comment: I think a better question is how to return one row when the following: SELECT CONCAT(SUM(AMOUNT), ' ',  `cateogry`.Name) returns two rows or more

Answer (score 1):

Start with a virtual table (subquery) with Category Total like this:

```
SELECT m.Category, SUM(m.Value) as Total
  FROM members m
 GROUP BY m.Category
 ORDER BY m.Category
```

Then do your concat like so, using your virtual table.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Category, ': ', Total) SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM (
    SELECT m.Category, SUM(m.Value) as Total
      FROM members m
     GROUP BY m.Category
     ORDER BY m.Category
  )A
```

Comment: virtual table was what i was looking for.

Comment: is it possible to add where clause from an outer select:  SELECT network.name, SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Category, ': ', Total) SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM (
    SELECT m.Category, SUM(m.Value) as Total
      FROM members m where category.netowrk = networks.Id
     GROUP BY m.Category
     ORDER BY m.Category
  )A from networks.  I'm currently getting an error saying that networks.Id does not exists